# Issue when attempting to create black and white image from previously processed image using file I/O in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I am making an application that takes an image and applies a grayscale filter to it using file i/o. Then the user is asked for a threshold and another save location that will take this processed image and make it pure black and white. The issue I am having is when the 2nd image is created and I try to open it, Windows reports the file is damaged even though the file size is the same as the processed image so it seems to be working correctly. Here is my code for the application. Also I would like to continue using file IO to create this, I understand Java has a built in function for creating a binary image.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Bitmapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String threshold;
        int thresholdInt;
        JFileChooser chooser1 = new JFileChooser();
        JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();
        JFileChooser chooser3 = new JFileChooser();
        int status1 = chooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
        int status2 = chooser2.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(status1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION && status2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {

            try
            {
                // Handling binary (not text) data, so use FileInputStream
                FileInputStream in  = new FileInputStream(chooser1.getSelectedFile());
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(chooser2.getSelectedFile() + "_gray.bmp");

                int i = 0;
                int counter = 0;


                while((i=in.read())!=-1) 
                {
                    if (++counter>54)   // skip past Bitmap headers
                    {
                        int b = i;
                        int g = in.read();
                        int r = in.read();

                        int gray = (b + g + r)/3;

                        out.write(gray);
                        out.write(gray);
                        i = gray;
                    }
                    out.write(i);
                }

                out.close();
                in.close();
                threshold = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a threshold to turn the picture black and white.");

                try
                {
                    thresholdInt = Integer.parseInt(threshold);
                    int status3 = chooser3.showSaveDialog(null);
                    if(status3 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        in = new FileInputStream(chooser2.getSelectedFile() + "_gray.bmp");
                        out = new FileOutputStream(chooser3.getSelectedFile() + "_bw.bmp");
                        while((i=in.read())!=-1) 
                        {
                            if (++counter>54)   // skip past Bitmap headers
                            {
                                int b = i;
                                int g = in.read();
                                int r = in.read();

                                if(b > thresholdInt)
                                    out.write(0);
                                else
                                    out.write(255);

                                if(g > thresholdInt)
                                    out.write(0);
                                else
                                    out.write(255);

                                if(r > thresholdInt)
                                    i = 0;
                                else
                                    i = 255;

                            }
                            out.write(i);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not select a save location for the second image.");
                } 

                catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Issue with user input, ensure you entered an integer. Error: " + ex);
                }



            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error in input/output of file:" + " '" + ex + "'");
            }

        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You did not specify a file or a save location for the new file.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit convoluted, but I can't see any clear mistakes in it. Are you certain that the headers size is 54 ?

Comment: There is clearly a problem with the fact that you don't reset the counter to 0 after creating the grayscale version before creating the bw one, but this shouldn't affect the second (gray) image, rather the bw one, as you'll corrupt the headers by thresholding their bits

Comment: Yep it really was as simple as setting the counter to 0 before processing the second. Thank you!

Comment: I'll create an answer for this, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not resetting to 0 the counter variable after creating the _gray image, before creating the _bw one. Therefore you are reading / writing the headers as color bytes, tresholding them and corrupting them. Resetting it should fix it.